# Parse XML tag into array not depend on XML structure

Tags: php, xml, parsing

Which is the quickest way in PHP to parse "category_fullname" texsts into array not depend on XML structure ?

```
...
<CATEGORY_ID>720</CATEGORY_ID>
<CATEGORY_NAME>Autorádiá</CATEGORY_NAME>
<CATEGORY_FULLNAME>Heureka.sk | Auto-moto | Autorádiá</CATEGORY_FULLNAME>
</CATEGORY>
<CATEGORY>
<CATEGORY_ID>881</CATEGORY_ID>
<CATEGORY_NAME>Alkohol testery</CATEGORY_NAME>
<CATEGORY_FULLNAME>Heureka.sk | Auto-moto | Alkohol testery</CATEGORY_FULLNAME>
</CATEGORY>
<CATEGORY>
<CATEGORY_ID>972</CATEGORY_ID>
<CATEGORY_NAME>Pneumatiky</CATEGORY_NAME>
<CATEGORY_FULLNAME>Heureka.sk | Auto-moto | Pneumatiky</CATEGORY_FULLNAME>
</CATEGORY>
<CATEGORY>
<CATEGORY_ID>1270</CATEGORY_ID>
<CATEGORY_NAME>Strešné boxy</CATEGORY_NAME>
<CATEGORY_FULLNAME>Heureka.sk | Auto-moto | Strešné boxy</CATEGORY_FULLNAME>
</CATEGORY>
<CATEGORY>
<CATEGORY_ID>1271</CATEGORY_ID>
<CATEGORY_NAME>Strešné nosiče</CATEGORY_NAME>
<CATEGORY>
<CATEGORY_ID>1268</CATEGORY_ID>
<CATEGORY_NAME>Nosiče lyží</CATEGORY_NAME>
<CATEGORY_FULLNAME>Heureka.sk | Auto-moto | Strešné nosiče | Nosiče lyží</CATEGORY_FULLNAME>
</CATEGORY>
<CATEGORY>
<CATEGORY_ID>1269</CATEGORY_ID>
<CATEGORY_NAME>Nosiče bicyklov</CATEGORY_NAME>
<CATEGORY_FULLNAME>Heureka.sk | Auto-moto | Strešné nosiče | Nosiče bicyklov</CATEGORY_FULLNAME>
</CATEGORY>
<CATEGORY>
<CATEGORY_ID>1312</CATEGORY_ID>
<CATEGORY_NAME>Nosiče vodné športy</CATEGORY_NAME>
<CATEGORY_FULLNAME>Heureka.sk | Auto-moto | Strešné nosiče | Nosiče vodné športy</CATEGORY_FULLNAME> ...
```

Array should looks like :

...

Heureka.sk | Auto-moto | Pneumatiky

Heureka.sk | Auto-moto | Strešné boxy

Heureka.sk | Auto-moto | Strešné nosiče | Nosiče lyží

...

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Function simplexml_load_file() and foreach function, but this way return structure. If i use file_get_contents() function return all with tags. Butif I try to parse by preg_match and try extract text between tag "category_fullname", return 0. The best will be to drop unnecessary tags except "category_fulname"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quickest way is to use simpleXML, array_map and xpath.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("test.xml")

$arrayCatNames = array_map('strval', $xml->xpath('//CATEGORY_FULLNAME'));
```

$xml->xpath returns an array of simple XML elements. '//CATEGORY_FULLNAME' searches for the tag anywhere in the XML. With array_map the function strval is applied to all elements to get the values.